# Amount in transaction

Tags: transactions

How can i get all transactions on account with embedded 'amount' value? Via REST API.

For example:
https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GCR7DQSRAFZHOC7QHPRNI7G55ZHF2EC2QA7V44XSX26WOJEV2Q7S42EW/transactions?order=desc

I think 'amount' should be there. But i don't see it.

I can see it in example
https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/transactions-for-account.html

But there is no amount in actually working API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the /payments endpoint:

https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GCR7DQSRAFZHOC7QHPRNI7G55ZHF2EC2QA7V44XSX26WOJEV2Q7S42EW/payments?order=desc

Comment: Aah.. well, looks like i missed this one somehow..

I see amount, yes. Also I see "from" and "to". So it is possible to determine pay-ins and pay-outs.

But )) no "memo". Also. I needed comination of "amount" and "memo" in one. In one request.

Comment: I managed to do it combining two requests.

https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GCR7DQSRAFZHOC7QHPRNI7G55ZHF2EC2QA7V44XSX26WOJEV2Q7S42EW/transactions?order=desc

and 

https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GCR7DQSRAFZHOC7QHPRNI7G55ZHF2EC2QA7V44XSX26WOJEV2Q7S42EW/effects?order=desc

I don't think it is nice. But it is working :)

Comment: It would be better to have a request with "amount" and "memo" in one place. Also to reduce server load.

Comment: There is also "transaction_hash" in your answer. So it is possible to combine this request with "transaction"-request.. to have "amount" there.

I would like to find out the solution with one request. But if there is no one. I think your answer is right.

( The second one is "effects". )

Thanks anyway. I think it would be useful.